# QML File Browser QDirModel vs QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to implement a QML based file browser. There are two file models in the Qt 5.1, QDirModel and QFileSystemModel, for QDirModel documentation says

> This class is obsolete. It is provided to keep old source code working. We strongly advise against using it in new code.

My code works with QDirModel but not with QFileSystemModel, here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDirModel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QQuickView view;

QDirModel model;

view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dirModel", &model);

view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
view.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

and here is main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle
{
    width: 400;
    height: 400;

    ListView
  {
    id: view;
    anchors.fill: parent;
    model: VisualDataModel
    {
      model: dirModel;
      delegate: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width;
        height: 40;

        Text
            {
                text: fileName
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code works but when I use QFileSystemModel instead of QDirModel it doesn't work ,that is, it doesn't display files properly.

Answer (score 2):

You really should use QFileSystemModel.
But if you don't know how to use it, look the doc more carefully, or use the 'FolderListModel' item directly in QML, it's in a 'Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.0' module, and it's already made to be used in QML, and quite easy to use. I myself have a file browser made with it.